# Index out of range error when implementing A-star path-finding algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, a-star, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to create character AI movement in a 2D RPG game (grid-based environment). Using the A* path-finding algorithm, I've successfully created varying paths for the character to walk on (representing his movement) however I'm encountering a recurring problem when I run/debug my game which I can't seem to solve:

I get an index out of range error due to the fact that the number of elements in my 'openList' becomes 0 at random times (variable: oCount). I've debugged much of the code trying to find the exact location where the openList loses its elements, but without any luck. I've narrowed it down to being at the end of the while loop. To test this, I used the following if statement and placed a breakpoint inside it:

```
if (oCount == 0 || openList.Count == 0)
    oCount = 0; //breakpoint added here
```

If you see '//**' in my code, this is where I put the above 'if statement' for testing.

I'm pretty new to programming, so please bear with me.

Here is the code for the AI class I made:

```
class AI
{
    List<Tile> openList;
    List<Tile> closedList;
    List<int> path; //represents the shortest path to travel in

    int cCount = 0;         // no. of elements in closedList
    int oCount = 0;         // no. of elements in openList

    public AI()
    {
        openList = new List<Tile>();
        closedList = new List<Tile>();
        path = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> FindPath(Tile[,] tile, Vector2 xBoundary, Vector2 yBoundary, Vector2 startTile, Vector2 endTile)
    {
        // [tile = elements of this array tell me the grid-position of the tile] 
        // [xBoundary + yBoundary = the rectangular boundary for where the character can move]
        // [startTile + endTile = the grid-location of the target tile and the tile the player is currently on]

        //Reset variables
        openList.Clear();
        closedList.Clear();
        path.Clear();
        tile[(int)startTile.X, (int)startTile.Y].PDir = 0; //[PDir = direction to parent tile]

        //Add starting tile to openList
        openList.Add(tile[(int)startTile.X, (int)startTile.Y]);

        //Set scores for starting tile
        openList[0].G = 0;
        openList[0].H = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - startTile.X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - startTile.Y);
        openList[0].F = openList[0].G + openList[0].H;

        //** Error occurred without debugger entering the 'if statement' here


        while (path.Count == 0)
        {
            oCount = openList.Count;

            //**

            //Sort openList by F score (i.e last element will have the lowest F score)
            openList = Sort(openList);

            //**

            //Move tile with lowest F score from openList to closedList
            closedList.Add(openList[oCount - 1]); //ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE!!
            openList.RemoveAt(oCount - 1);
            cCount = closedList.Count;


            //Add valid surrounding tiles to openList AND Alter valid existing tiles (I will condense this into a method later, when everything is working)
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Each following for-loop checks the two nearest x- or y- grid positions

            // a = difference in grid x-position
            for (int a = -1; a < 2; a += 2)
            {
                //If tile is walkable[1], not in closed list[2], and within set boundaries[3-4]...
                if (tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].Collision == false
                    && !closedList.Contains(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y])
                    && closedList[cCount - 1].X + a >= xBoundary.X && closedList[cCount - 1].X + a <= xBoundary.Y      
                    && closedList[cCount - 1].Y >= yBoundary.X && closedList[cCount - 1].Y <= yBoundary.Y)
                {
                    //If tile not in open list...
                    if (!openList.Contains(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y]))
                    {
                        //Add tile to openList
                        openList.Add(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y]);
                        oCount = openList.Count;

                        //Set direction to parent tile
                        if (a == -1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 1;
                        else if (a == 1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 3;

                        //Calculate F, G and H
                        openList[oCount - 1].G = closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1;
                        openList[oCount - 1].H = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - openList[oCount - 1].X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - openList[oCount - 1].Y);
                        openList[oCount - 1].F = openList[oCount - 1].G + openList[oCount - 1].H;

                    }
                    //otherwise, check if current path is better than the previous path that tile had...
                    else if (closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1 < tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].G)
                    {
                        //Set new direction to parent tile
                        if (a == -1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 1;
                        else if (a == 1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 3;

                        //Re-calculate G and H values
                        int g = closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1;
                        int h = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].Y);

                        //Set values to tile
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].G = g;
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].H = h;
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].F = g + h;     //including f-value...

                        //**
                    }
                }
            }

            // b = difference in grid y-position
            for (int b = -1; b < 2; b += 2)
            {
                //If tile is walkable, not in closed list, and within set boundaries...
                if (tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].Collision == false
                    && !closedList.Contains(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b])
                    && closedList[cCount - 1].X >= xBoundary.X && closedList[cCount - 1].X <= xBoundary.Y
                    && closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b >= yBoundary.X && closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b <= yBoundary.Y)
                {
                    //If tile not in open list...
                    if (!openList.Contains(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b]))
                    {
                        //Add tile to openList
                        openList.Add(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b]);
                        oCount = openList.Count;

                        //Set new parent tile direction
                        if (b == -1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].PDir = 2;
                        else if (b == 1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].PDir = 4;

                        //Calculate F, G and H
                        openList[oCount - 1].G = closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1;
                        openList[oCount - 1].H = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - openList[oCount - 1].X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - openList[oCount - 1].Y);
                        openList[oCount - 1].F = openList[oCount - 1].G + openList[oCount - 1].H;

                    }
                    //otherwise, check if current path is better than the previous path that tile had...
                    else if (closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1 < tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].G)
                    {
                        //Set new parent tile direction
                        if (b == -1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].PDir = 2;
                        else if (b == 1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].PDir = 4;

                        //Re-calculate G and H values
                        int g = closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1;
                        int h = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].Y);

                        //Set values to tile
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].G = g;
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].H = h;
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X, closedList[cCount - 1].Y + b].F = g + h;     //including f-value...

                        //**
                    }
                }
            }

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            //If end tile is reached (i.e at end of path)...
            if (closedList[cCount - 1].Y == endTile.Y && closedList[cCount - 1].X == endTile.X)
            {
                //tile[(int)endTile.X, (int)endTile.Y].PDir = 0;
                path = PlotPath(tile, tile[(int)startTile.X, (int)startTile.Y], tile[(int)endTile.X, (int)endTile.Y]); //plot the shortest route/path
            }
        }

        //** Breakpoint here tells me oCount reaches 0

        return path;
    }

    private List<Tile> Sort(List<Tile> list)
    {
        Tile temp;
        bool swapMade = true;           //tells whether a swap was made during an iteration
        short a = 0;

        while (swapMade)
        {
            //reset
            swapMade = false;
            a++;

            for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0 + a; i--)
            {
                if (list[i].F > list[i - 1].F)
                {
                    //swap
                    temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[i - 1];
                    list[i - 1] = temp;

                    swapMade = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    private List<int> PlotPath(Tile[,] tileArray, Tile startingTile, Tile endingTile)
    {
        //**

        Tile currentTile = endingTile;
        List<int> pathList = new List<int>();

        //**

        while (currentTile.PDir != 0) // PDir of 0 indicates that we've reached the starting Tile (i.e the path has been fully plotted). When the character moves, it follows this path in reverse order
        {
            if (currentTile.PDir == 1)
            {
                pathList.Add(3);
                currentTile = tileArray[currentTile.X + 1, currentTile.Y];
            }
            else if (currentTile.PDir == 2)
            {
                pathList.Add(4);
                currentTile = tileArray[currentTile.X, currentTile.Y + 1];
            }
            else if (currentTile.PDir == 3)
            {
                pathList.Add(1);
                currentTile = tileArray[currentTile.X - 1, currentTile.Y];
            }
            else if (currentTile.PDir == 4)
            {
                pathList.Add(2);
                currentTile = tileArray[currentTile.X, currentTile.Y - 1];
            }
        }

        //**

        return pathList;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks Peter Duniho for explaining to me where I'm lacking in my question. With that, I've added in all the code that uses oCount/openList.

Hope my code is legible. I'm sure there's much that can be improved in it.

Comment: I'd like to know what the reason is for the down votes I'm receiving

Answer (score 1):

The down votes are probably because of the combination of an incomplete code example, and what appears to be a minimal effort to debug the issue yourself. But, what the heck…I'll offer as much information can be given as an answer based on the question as posted…

What is known and what can be inferred from what is known:

- The failure occurs at the expression `openList[oCount - 1]`
- `IndexOutOfRangeException` is being thrown

Further, while it is impossible to verify your claim (due to the incomplete code example), we may as well assume that it is true that `oCount` does not have the value 0 when this exception occurs (it would have been better for you to be more specific; describing what *is* true is a lot more useful than describing some random fact that is *not* true).

This assumption along with the two facts tell us that the value of `oCount` is non-zero and greater than the length of the list (which, again according to your statements, is apparently zero at this point).

- The variable `oCount` is initialized just two statements earlier, to the length of the list
- The only intervening statement is a call to some `Sort()` method

These two facts, along with the earlier inferences, tell us that the length of the list is changing somehow between the initialization of `oCount` and the expression where `oCount` is being used.

Unfortunately, the variable `openList` is apparently not a local variable (why?! that seems like a really bad idea), and is not even initialized in this method. So it is not possible to tell from the code example where else the object might be modified.

That gives us at least *two* possible explanations:

1. The `Sort()` method is reducing the length of the list
2. There is some other thread around that is modifying the list for some reason

If I had to bet, I would guess #1 is the issue. Mainly because there's nothing else about the question that even mentions a second thread.

Finally, note: even if the length of the list was zero when you initialized `oCount`, you'd still get the same exception, because `oCount - 1` would be -1 and still out of range of the valid index values for the list (0 would be out of range, for that matter). So the above relies heavily on your claim that `oCount` is *not* zero while the list length actually is zero.

If the above doesn't get you pointed in the right direction and you really want help, you need to post a good code example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Greatly appreciated. I've updated the question and hope it now meets the standards. I've also narrowed down the problem further. Hope this helps. I'll look at tidying my code as well. Still getting the hang of it

Comment: I also thought the Sort() method was problem, however as you can see, it isn't. I debugged just before and after it is called, and oCount remains the same. I haven't given a properties method to oCount either, so it isn't being changed anywhere else in the code. These are all the methods associated with it. If I were to guess, given my debugging, the problem should lie with the 'else if' inside both for-loops... yet there is no alteration of oCount here. As for your 'final note,' openList is initialized with 0 elements, but we can see that new elements are added immediately afterwards.

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is this:
1. openList is cleared (0 elements)
2. Element added to openList (1)
3. Move element from openList to closedList (0)
4. Method to 'add valid surrounding tiles to openList' -> None are added (openList remains with 0 elements)
5. While-loop initiated again once we reach the end of it. Tries to move the element in openList to closedList. Error..

The thing is, there are valid tiles during these errors. And the error can occur immediately, or 2min into the game. With this, it doesn't seem like any specific group of tiles are causing a problem