# A-star path finding algorithm:- closedList using all elements in openList (causing index out of range)

Tags: c#, a-star, indexoutofrangeexception

- oCount = num of elements in openList
- cCount = num of elements in closedList

I'm implementing A-star without diagonal movement in a tile-based environment. Every so often, an 'index out of range error' is thrown on my openList when I try to access the last element in it (using [oCount - 1] when oCount = 0). oCount only becomes 0 when cCount is 159 though, which suggests that closedList has used every element in openList. Here is an example:

cCount becomes 159 -> oCount is 0 -> Check tiles surrounding the tile in closedList[158] -> No valid tiles -> Return to beginning of while-loop -> Try to move last element in openList to closedList (error)

Here is my FindPath() method:
*(The grid-position of a tile is based on its position in the array (i.e tile[0,0] is the tile at the top-left corner)*

```
//xBound + yBound = the bounding area with which the character can walk
public List<int> FindPath(Tile[,] tile, Vector2 xBoundary, Vector2 yBoundary, Vector2 startTile, Vector2 endTile)
    {
        //Initialize variables
        List<Tile> openList = new List<Tile>();
        List<Tile> closedList = new List<Tile>();
        List<int> path = new List<int>();
        int cCount = 0;  
        int oCount = 0;

        tile[(int)startTile.X, (int)startTile.Y].PDir = 0; //PDir = direction to its parent tile

        //Add starting tile to openList
        openList.Add(tile[(int)startTile.X, (int)startTile.Y]);

        //Set scores for starting tile
        openList[0].G = 0;
        openList[0].H = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - startTile.X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - startTile.Y);
        openList[0].F = openList[0].G + openList[0].H;


        while (path.Count == 0)
        {
            oCount = openList.Count;

            //Sort openList by decreasing F score
            openList = Sort(openList);

            //Move tile with lowest F score from openList to closedList
            closedList.Add(openList[oCount - 1]); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
            openList.RemoveAt(oCount - 1);
            cCount = closedList.Count;


            //Add valid surrounding tiles OR Alter valid existing tiles
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            for (int a = -1; a < 2; a += 2) //[a = difference in grid x-position]
            {
                //If tile is walkable, not in closed list, and within set boundaries...
                if (tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].Collision == false
                    && !closedList.Contains(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y])
                    && closedList[cCount - 1].X + a >= xBoundary.X && closedList[cCount - 1].X + a <= xBoundary.Y       //Test if boundaries must be < or <=
                    && closedList[cCount - 1].Y >= yBoundary.X && closedList[cCount - 1].Y <= yBoundary.Y)
                {
                    //If tile not in open list...
                    if (!openList.Contains(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y]))
                    {
                        //Add tile
                        openList.Add(tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y]);
                        oCount = openList.Count;

                        //Set parent direction
                        if (a == -1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 1;
                        else if (a == 1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 3;

                        //Calculate F, G and H
                        openList[oCount - 1].G = closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1;
                        openList[oCount - 1].H = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - openList[oCount - 1].X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - openList[oCount - 1].Y);
                        openList[oCount - 1].F = openList[oCount - 1].G + openList[oCount - 1].H;

                    }
                    //otherwise, check if current path is better than the previous path that tile had...
                    else if (closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1 < tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].G)
                    {
                        //Set new parent direction
                        if (a == -1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 1;
                        else if (a == 1)
                            tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].PDir = 3;

                        //Re-calculate G and H values
                        int g = closedList[cCount - 1].G + 1;
                        int h = (int)Math.Abs(endTile.X - tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].X) + (int)Math.Abs(endTile.Y - tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].Y);

                        //Set values to tile
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].G = g;
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].H = h;
                        tile[closedList[cCount - 1].X + a, closedList[cCount - 1].Y].F = g + h;     //including f-value...
                    }
                }
            }

            // Above for-loop repeated for [b = difference in y-position]

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            //If at endTile...
            if (closedList[cCount - 1].Y == endTile.Y && closedList[cCount - 1].X == endTile.X)
            {
                path = PlotPath(tile, tile[(int)startTile.X, (int)startTile.Y], tile[(int)endTile.X, (int)endTile.Y]);
            }
        }

        return path;
    }
```

As far as I can tell, this seems to be a problem with my algorithm

--

--Edit--

As requested by user3444160, here is the stack trace (I believe):

```
Mini RPG (test1).exe!Mini_RPG__test1_.AI.FindPath(Mini_RPG__test1_.Tile[,] tile, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2 xBoundary, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2 yBoundary, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2 startTile, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2 endTile) Line 45  C#

Mini RPG (test1).exe!Mini_RPG__test1_.Character1.UpdateDecisions(Mini_RPG__test1_.Tile[,] tileArray) Line 106 + 0xa9 bytes  C#

Mini RPG (test1).exe!Mini_RPG__test1_.Character1.Update(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime, Mini_RPG__test1_.Tile[,] tileArray) Line 69 + 0xb bytes  C#

Mini RPG (test1).exe!Mini_RPG__test1_.Game1.Update(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) Line 745 + 0x28 bytes C#

[External Code] 
Mini RPG (test1).exe!Mini_RPG__test1_.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 15 + 0xb bytes   C#
```

Comment: What is the actual exception you are getting?  What is the stack trace?  Have you tried to debug through it?

Comment: @user3444160 I'm getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I'm basically trying to access openList[-1]. Forgive me but I'm pretty new to programming so I'm not familiar with stack traces. I've been debugging since Sunday. I've narrowed down the possibilities to what I have now and not sure I can get much further (though maybe with stack traces I can?). I'd prefer to understand how to figure out my problem, but I'm aware that answers here are based directly on the questions provided. [EDIT: Stack trace info added to question. Let me know if it is ok]

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert's excellent description of a simple A-star implementation in C#:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/04/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-two.aspx. YOur implementation will not work on any non-trivial graph because of using inappropriate data structures for the OpenSet and ClosedSet.

Comment: If you're interested, I've implemented similar problem in the past (https://github.com/svejdo1/astar)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll check them out. Still wondering how my closedList is using all openList elements. I think it's important for me to understand where I was going wrong here

Comment: @meestaman: If you would like readers to *actually* read your code above, try *actually* formatting said code so that it is *actually* readable in the code window.

Comment: Are you in the same class with Shane? Because you seem to have the exact same problem with the exact same code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749663/index-out-of-range-error-when-implementing-a-star-path-finding-algorithm

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Yes! I am, lol. We're working on the same game together. Didn't realize he had also asked this very question (woops)... I should rightfully have some votes deducted for that. On the bright side, seems I made a little more progress than he did with the problem.

Comment: "seems I made a little more progress than he did with the problem" -- that's true. But you would still need to post a complete code example to get help for it here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterDuniho: What more would be needed? I'm cautious not have too much code here. Anyone would be turned off by that!

Comment: I felt the MCVE link I offered provides useful guidance. If that's not sufficient, check these also: http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints, http://sscce.org/, http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html, http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/incomplete.html